# Appending a class from external URL in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code snippet in jquery , which appends a element 'new-item' to the existing element 'item' as per following code.

```
$("#new-item").appendTo("#item");
```

HTML coding after appending the ID in index.html

```
<li id="item">Old item</li>
<li id="new-item">New item</li>
```

My question is suppose I have a page about.html and it have following html code.

```
 <li id="about-item">About us </li>
```

I need to append the same id "about-item" to index.html as follows.

```
 <li id="item">Old item</li>
 <li id="new-item">New item</li>
 <li id="about-item">About us </li>
```

Can anybody suggest how can i do it? Can we do it through ajax ? It is about calling a element from external url source and appending it to current page.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all, what do you mean with "which appends a class", really, the snippet you posted appends the items that have class `.item` to the first element that has a class `new-item`,

Comment: typo corrected.do you have any feasible solution?

Answer (score -1):

This code snippet will get the external CSS sheet containing the 'new-class', and will append a new li in your list (in this case a ul) with the new class and new content :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com">
$(function(){
 $("<ul>").append("<li class='new-class'>New Contents</li>");
});
```

Just make sure to call the stylesheet link BEFORE your jquery code.

Comment: I don't understand this theory

Comment: Theory ? Just get the stylsheet class CDN on. Then whenever you want it remove the existing class and apply the new one. Should be simple enough mate !

Comment: I assume you didn't understand my question, what I asked is how to append a class or layer from an external page not loading about a css contents but something appending like      <li class="new-item">New contents</li> to      <li class="item">old contents</li>

Comment: You are correct i did misunderstand. Good news is, solution should be simple. Ill edit my answer

Comment: Sorry this is not the solution iam looking

Comment: Please help someone who is experienced on this issue

Comment: I would suggest to edit the question to be more clear. Good luck

Answer (score -2):

Can you try this?

```
$(".item").addClass("new-item");
```

Comment: Your code can't help, please provide some description and consider that append a class doesn't require the `dot` character, but just `.addClass('new-item')`.

Comment: Oh sorry,  reomove the dot inside the addClass `$(".item").addClass("new-item");`